# Java script to do list

Tags: javascript

Im trying to make a to do list with js its my first project with the language.

```js
 var row = 0;

function addItem() {
  var Items = getList();
  var item = document.getElementById("todoInput").value;
  var text = document.createTextNode(item);
  var newItem = document.createElement("li");
  newItem.appendChild(text);
  newItem.setAttribute('id', 'todoItem'+row)
  document.getElementById("todoList").appendChild(newItem);
  Items.push(item);
  localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(Items));

  var removeItem = document.createElement('input')
  removeItem.setAttribute('type', 'button');
  removeItem.setAttribute('value', 'remove');
  removeItem.setAttribute('id', 'removeButton');
  removeItem.setAttribute('onclick', 'deleterow(' + row + ')');

  newItem.appendChild(removeItem);
 row++;

}

function getList() {
  var Items = new Array;
  var ItemsStr = localStorage.getItem('todo');
  if (ItemsStr != null) {
    Items = JSON.parse(ItemsStr);
  }
  return Items;
}
var Items = getList();
for (tdl of Items) {
  console.log(tdl)
  var text = document.createTextNode(Items);
  var newItem = document.createElement("li");
  newItem.appendChild(text);
  document.getElementById("todoList").appendChild(newItem);
}

function deleterow(ID) {
  document.getElementById('todoItem'+ID).remove()
}

function removeAll() {
 document.getElementById('todoList').innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>To do list</title>

<body manifest="todo.appcache">
  <h1>To do list</h1>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="todoInput">
    <button type="button" onclick="addItem()">Add</button>
  </form>
  <ol id="todoList">
  </ol>

  <script src="todo.js">


  </script>
</body>
```

there is the code. what I need to stop it from repeating the entire array when the page is refreshed and instead show the array in order as it was entered and I need to figure out how to fix the remove all and remove button. The remove button removes the item from the visible list but not the array. page hosted here: http://bryanthe.net/to-do-list/

Comment: Running your code snippet throws an error saying `"message": "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag."`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're wondering about but here:

```
for (tdl of Items) {
  console.log(tdl)
  var text = document.createTextNode(Items);
  var newItem = document.createElement("li");
  newItem.appendChild(text);
  document.getElementById("todoList").appendChild(newItem);
}
```

You create text node with `Items` - (the entire list)

Try to instead create it with `tdl`  - (the item of the current iteration)

Comment: i got that just before you sent your answer, but now my problem is the code does not remove the item from the array when removed so once you reload it comes back. What would I do to stop that. i used delete... (i forgot the rest) and it just threw a thousand errors and broke everything. so im not sure what would work